# on add button click data insert twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyManageConnectionString"].ToString());
    string InstituteId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["InstituteId"].Value;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label)Master.FindControl("lblPageName")).Text = "Employee List";
        ((Label)Master.FindControl("lblPageName")).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        ((Label)Master.FindControl("lblPageName1")).Text = " Employee List";
        if (Request.Cookies["InstituteId"] == null)
        {
            string OriginalUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
            string LoginPageUrl = "INlogin.aspx";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?R={1}", LoginPageUrl, OriginalUrl));
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }


    private void BindData()
    {
        string strQuery = "select * from tblEmployee where InstituteId=@InstituteId";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstituteId", InstituteId);
        gvEmpList.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        gvEmpList.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string txtEmployeeName = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmployeeName")).Text;
        string txtEmployeeAddress = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmployeeAddress")).Text;
        string txtEmployeeEmailId = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmployeeEmailId")).Text;
        string txtMobile = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMobile")).Text;
        string txtBirthDate = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtBirthDate")).Text;
        string txtdateOfJoining = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtdateOfJoining")).Text;
        string txtExperiance = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtExperiance")).Text;
        string txtLastSchoolDetails = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastSchoolDetails")).Text;
        string txtSalaryDetails = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSalaryDetails")).Text;
        bool chkmerriageStatus = ((CheckBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("chkmerriageStatus")).Checked;
        string txtNationality = ((TextBox)gvEmpList.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNationality")).Text;

        try
        {

            //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //con.Open();
            //cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblEmployee (InstituteId, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress, EmployeeEmailId, Mobile, BirthDate, dateOfJoining, Experiance, LastSchoolDetails, SalaryDetails, merriageStatus, Nationality, ActivationCode, ActivationStatus, Password) VALUES (@InstituteId, @EmployeeName, @EmployeeAddress, @EmployeeEmailId, @Mobile, @BirthDate, @dateOfJoining, @Experiance, @LastSchoolDetails, @SalaryDetails, @merriageStatus, @Nationality, @ActivationCode, @ActivationStatus, @Password);" + "select * from tblEmployee where InstituteId=@InstituteId";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstituteId", InstituteId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", txtEmployeeName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeAddress", txtEmployeeAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeEmailId", txtEmployeeEmailId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", txtBirthDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfJoining", txtdateOfJoining);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Experiance", txtExperiance);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastSchoolDetails", txtLastSchoolDetails);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalaryDetails", txtSalaryDetails);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@merriageStatus", chkmerriageStatus);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", txtNationality);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationCode", ActivationCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationStatus", false);
            string GTPassword = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(8, 3);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", GTPassword);
            //int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //con.Close();
            //if (result == 1)
            //{
            //    sendActivation(ActivationCode, txtEmployeeName, txtEmployeeEmailId);
            //    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('Registration Successfull')", true);

            //}
            //else {
            //    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('Registration Fail')", true);
            //}
            gvEmpList.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            gvEmpList.DataBind();

            //BindData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }

    }
```

When the add button is clicked `btnAdd_click` inserts data twice. Also I am not getting any exception errors in `btnadd_click` code.

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="dvGrid" style="overflow-x: scroll; Overflow: scroll;">
            
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEmployeeList" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="gvEmpList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmployeeId" CssClass="gvmydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="gvpager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvheader" RowStyle-CssClass="gvrows" ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvEmpList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="gvEmpList_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvEmpList_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvEmpList_RowCancelingEdit" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EmployeeId")%>'
                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
                                        Text="Delete" OnClick="lnkRemove_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeId" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="EmployeeId">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        <%--    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="InstituteId" SortExpression="InstituteId">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="txtInstituteId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InstituteId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblInstituteId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InstituteId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeName" SortExpression="EmployeeName">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeAddress" SortExpression="EmployeeAddress">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeAddress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeEmailId" SortExpression="EmployeeEmailId">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeEmailId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeEmailId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeEmailId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeEmailId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeEmailId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile" SortExpression="Mobile">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mobile") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMobile" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mobile") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BirthDate" SortExpression="BirthDate">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BirthDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBirthDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BirthDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dateOfJoining" SortExpression="dateOfJoining">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdateOfJoining" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dateOfJoining") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdateOfJoining" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbldateOfJoining" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dateOfJoining") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Experiance" SortExpression="Experiance">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtExperiance" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Experiance") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtExperiance" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblExperiance" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Experiance") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastSchoolDetails" SortExpression="LastSchoolDetails">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastSchoolDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastSchoolDetails") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastSchoolDetails" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastSchoolDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastSchoolDetails") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SalaryDetails" SortExpression="SalaryDetails">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalaryDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SalaryDetails") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalaryDetails" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSalaryDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SalaryDetails") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="merriageStatus" SortExpression="merriageStatus">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmerriageStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("merriageStatus") %>' />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmerriageStatus" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmerriageStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("merriageStatus") %>' Enabled="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nationality" SortExpression="Nationality">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNationality" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nationality") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNationality" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNationality" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nationality") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <%--<FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>--%>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gvheader" />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="gvpager" />
                        <RowStyle CssClass="gvrows" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                                        
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvEmpList" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

When I click on add button, footer item data will insert into my database but is insert twice.  It is in debug mode and jumping around everywhere.
it show "The process or thread has changed since last step."

Comment: code looks ok ..do one thing when you click on button set a flag and check when it comes again  for insertion and if flag is true then redirect where ever you want

Comment: when i m debug it show the process or thread has changed since last steps and jump up again up line code and down

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the insert command again by calling `gvEmpList.DataSource = GetData(cmd);` inside `btnAdd_Click`. Please check it. The `cmd` object inside `btnAdd_Click` is an insert command.

Comment: i also remove gvEmpList>DataSource=Getdata(cmd); and use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); both have same problem in debug mode and jumping up line and downl line. it show "The process or thread has changed since last step."

Answer (score 0):

Remove following code from `btnAdd_Click`

```
gvEmpList.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
gvEmpList.DataBind();
```

And call following method

```
BindData();
```

Comment: when i used BindData() method data was not insert

Comment: Have you removed only two lines which i mentioned ?

Comment: yes. two line remove and and debug but data was not store in database

Comment: You haven't called `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` in `btnAdd_click`.